# Casting a string to JInternalFrame

Tags: java, swing, casting, persistence, jinternalframe

I've got a String that was a JInternalFrame.toString() I've written to a file, and now I need a way to load that back as a JInternalFrame. The string of data looks like

`javax.swing.JInternalFrame[,0,0,500x400,invalid,hidden,layout=javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicInternalFrameUI$Handler,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=com.apple.laf.AquaInternalFrameUI$CompoundUIBorder@2e00e753,flags=16777216,maximumSize=,minimumSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=150,height=65],preferredSize=,closable=true,defaultCloseOperation=DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE,desktopIcon=javax.swing.JInternalFrame$JDesktopIcon[,0,0,64x64,invalid,hidden,layout=java.awt.BorderLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=0,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=],frameIcon=,iconable=false,isClosed=false,isIcon=false,isMaximum=false,isSelected=false,maximizable=true,opened=false,resizable=true,rootPane=javax.swing.JRootPane[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=javax.swing.JRootPane$RootLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=449,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=],rootPaneCheckingEnabled=true,title=Test app]`

I know a String can't be cast to a JInternalFrame, but there must be some sort of way to convert it. How would I do that?

Comment: You shouldn't do this, period. Why not instead save the state of your JInternalFrame (or better, the state or your model) to a state class, save it via serialization and then use the state data to reconstruct your JinternalFrame? Trying to use the toString() for this purpose is utter nonsense. And thinking that casting has any utility here is worse than nonsense. Sorry to be blunt, but this question demands bluntless.

Comment: What you want is some form of serialization.  ToString generally does not give you that.

Comment: You could try parsing the String your self, but it would probably be missing stuff you need, like it's content. Can you explain what it is you hope to achieve (why are you saving the frame in the first place)?

Comment: I would love to serialize the JInternalFrame, but every time I try to, it throws an exception from somewhere in the JLabel class.

Comment: Then you're doing your serialization or something else wrong, and we can perhaps help you with this, if you tell us more, but don't go down the road of trying to imitate serialization with a component's `toString()` because again this plan is utter foolishness or worse. Again, concern yourself with the state of your model not your GUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't try to serialize a `JInternalFrame`. Why? From the [Javadoc for `JInternalFrame`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JInternalFrame.html):

> **Warning**: Serialized objects of this class will not be compatible with
>   future Swing releases. The current serialization support is
>   appropriate for short term storage or RMI between applications running
>   the same version of Swing. As of 1.4, support for long term storage of
>   all JavaBeans<sup>TM</sup> has been added to the java.beans package. Please see
>   [XMLEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/XMLEncoder.html).

I would listen to the warning and look at implementing `XMLEncoder` into your program instead.

Comment: As you answer suggests, the OP could use the `XMLEncoder` instead of trying to serialize the result (via an `ObjectWriter`), that doesn't mean that they "shouldn't" save the frame - but I would agree, there is probably a better solution the saving the entire state of the object and it's children...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Agreed, I wouldn't do it myself, but the choice is up to the OP.

Comment: Thank you, this will work very well. I'm glad someone was able to look over the stupidity of my question, and find an answer. I'm at wit's last end. This problem has had me for days. Thank you.